# Hashtables & Linked Lists -- All pointers, but no nodes?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, hashmap, hashtable

I just finished reading this excellent post on hashtables [What is a hash table and how do you make it in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930046/what-is-a-hash-table-and-how-do-you-make-it-in-c/31930047#31930047) My question is this: Why is it that we are constantly mallocing node pointers instead of actual nodes based on our struct? Is creating a struct node pointer just as good as creating the struct itself? I thought, with respect to the linked lists in our hashtable, we needed both a pointer to our struct nodes, in addition to the nodes themselves.  I know I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what. Any insight or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `node* newptr = malloc(sizeof(node));` allocates memory for a `node` and puts the *address* of that node in `newptr`. So it's not allocating a pointer, it *is* allocating an actual node.

Comment: @user3386109 Ok. So, the existence of the address returned by malloc implies the existence of the struct node. Many thanks!

Comment: always check the return of `malloc`.. if it gives you NULL it was unable to allocate enough space for your request, and you'll have to gracefully handle that error

Comment: `node* newptr = malloc(sizeof(node));` you are right we a allocating a node pointer, but the pointer points to a space of `sizeof(node)` in memory its essentially a node that the pointer points to.