# Key-Value pair in C?

Tags: c, parsing, key-value, keyvaluepair

I have a string in the format of

```
"SERVERID=12345\nSERVERKEY=asdasw\nSERVERAPPID=123213\n"
```

I've parsed this line by line using `strtok()`.
Is there a way to make a key-value pair of each line? Like maybe store them in some sort of an array? What I mean is, if I want `SERVERID`, I just say `Array['SERVERID']` and it'll return `12345` as the value. Is there a way to do it in C?

Comment: No. Welcome to C.

Comment: There are (non-standard) ways to achieve more or less the result, but not using the notation you suggest.  The string should be in double quotes, and you'd need to use a function call to do the lookup, and you'd use a structure behind the scenes, and you'd have other functions to create the array of key-value pairs, and to add key-value pairs, and to remove them, and so on.  It would be done using functions all the way around.

Comment: will `find(dict, "SERVERID")` do?

Comment: You need to write your own data structure for that in C. If you can write it in C++ i would use that and use a map that's built in

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is there an example code of such an implementation?

Comment: I'm thinking of the code in "C Interfaces and Implementations: Techniques for Creating Reusable
Software" by D R Hanson (Addison-Wesley Professional Computing Series, 1997,
ISBN 0-201-49841-3).  Source etc available from GitHub (https://github.com/drh/cii).

Comment: Depending on your implementation, your could try the functions `hsearch` or `lsearch`. They are not standard C but exist on most posix systems.

Answer (score 3):

Standard C doesn't give you any "container types" like the one you're looking for. Still you have several options to solve your problem:

1. Might sound silly, but you could switch to a different language. It's at least something to think about. For example, C++ comes to mind, offering the [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) type.
2. Use some third-party library. A popular choice is [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/), it offers a [hash table](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) you could use.
3. There's always the option to implement it yourself. A very simple idea would be to use an array of a struct, e.g.

   ```
   struct stringpair {
       char *key;
       char *value;
   };

   struct stringpair *table;

   // ...
   size_t entries = 42; // number of entries you found
   table = malloc(entries * sizeof *table); // check for NULL after this

   // look for an entry:
   char *value = 0;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < entries; ++i)
   {
       if (!strcmp(table[i].key, "SERVERID"))
       {
           value = table[i].value;
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

   This is of course a **very** basic solution and doesn't perform well with a lot of entries. I also didn't test this code, it's just to give you a rough idea. If you need fast lookups, you will need to implement a hashtable instead, or use option 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for here would be a form of a dictionary. Typically, but not always, these use hashtables. There are many ways of creating a hashtable in C

You can find your answer here:
[What is a hash table and how do you make it in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930046/what-is-a-hash-table-and-how-do-you-make-it-in-c)

You could also see other implementations such as a combined data structures, like a dictionary-linked list, and more. Just find a way to convert your string (char *) into a number, and find a way to use that number as an index.

Comment: This looks more as a comment instead of answer.

Comment: I don't have commenting privileges yet, but would have liked to answer this question anyways. Do you recommend I delete it? if so, could I have a further explanation as not to make the same mistake down the road?

Comment: I'd say it's not a good answer, still the link and short explanation could be helpful, so, it's not a *bad* one either -> keep it.