# How I create Dictionary where my values are Queue in C?

Tags: c

I have Queue  with  contains a structure and my problem is how to forward queue to dictionary and how to implement this dictionary for example : `Dictionary<int,Queue>` ?

Comment: I need this dictionary :  Dictionary<int,Queue>  :)

Comment: Look at this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930046/what-is-a-hash-table-and-how-do-you-make-it-in-c