# What's the difference between a hash table and a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, c, dictionary, hashtable

I am starting to learn about the hash table data structure in C, and I've noticed (if I understand the concept correctly) that hash tables are awfully similar to python dictionaries. If I am incorrect and they are two completely different things, could someone explain to me what a hash table is without getting too technical? Thanks.

Comment: They are not entirely different things. The concept is the same, though the implementation will be specific to different versions of CPython

Comment: As far as I am aware, they are implemented in a similar way. Each index is used to generate a hash to locate the value at the given index

Comment: They are basically the same thing. Key/value stores with more efficient lookups via hash.

Comment: This question is essentially analogous to "what is the difference between a car and a Ford Focus". Python dicts fall under the category of hash tables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are Python's Built In Dictionaries Implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented)

Comment: The dupe obviously is more broad than your question, but the answer by Aaron Hall quite clearly states that they are hash tables in Python and there's plenty of detail in there for you to reconcile your C learning with CPython

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a hash table and how do you make it in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930046/what-is-a-hash-table-and-how-do-you-make-it-in-c)

Comment: Python dictionaries are hash tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not really any difference between them. That's why python's dicts don't support duplicates. That is also why python has the function `hash` which python's dictionaries use by default.

Comment: "The second one is the one which takes in a custom hash function" - what? No it doesn't. `mapping` is a dict or other key-value data structure, not a hash function.