# Why would I use a data structure(e.g. hash table) instead of an array?

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, hashtable

This will probably sound dumb but I am trying to make an efficient program (time/memory wise) and studying hash tables I have seen that it's basically an array of linked lists, that start filling up when all the spots in the table are taken. And this starts demanding memory and time because they need mallocs to store data and time to search an element, unlike an array; this is all because arrays are not dynamic and have a limit

So I was just wondering, why can't I make a 20 billion long array so I can access in O(1) using the indexes and there is no need for mallocs? Like, a huge array in the main and that's all

i need to save a text as a bunch of lines, so i know where each line is (line 1 will be the first, duh) and it did seem unnecessary to me to use hash table but the problem is I don't know how many lines it will have so if i make an array of 50 maybe it's not enough, I am wondering if it is better to use a list/hash table/ some other structure or just an array of char arrays

Comment: If you already have the index of the item you're looking for, you don't need a hash table.  The presumption is that you don't have the index.

Comment: You use a hash table when you don't have an index, because you're using something like a string as the key.

Comment: Also, if the indexes in use are distributed sparsely throughout the array, allocating an array with 20 billion elements is a big waste of memory.

Comment: Also, a huge sparse array will probably be _slower_ than a hash table due to poor cache utilization.

Comment: How is your program going to be efficient memory wise if you’re going to allocate memory for 20 billion elements every time?

Comment: @Barmar in this case I have to manage a text so the indexes are the text's lines and I know them but I don't know how long the text is, so I was wondering what is the best storage

Comment: Each text should be a dynamically-allocated string. The elements of the hash table or array would be pointers to those strings.

Comment: In case you need to search the element you need through an input string, the complexity won't be O(1) but O(N), as you will have to traverse the whole array and compare each string of the array with the input one. Hash tables definitely increase access speed but the required memory is increased as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a hash table and how do you make it in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930046/what-is-a-hash-table-and-how-do-you-make-it-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

> This will probably sound dumb but I am trying to make an efficient program (time/memory wise)

Efficient program to do *what*?  You never really say what you're trying to do.

> studying hash tables I have seen that it's basically an array of linked lists

That's a common implementation, but it doesn't speak to why you'd use a hash table in the first place.

You use a hash table when you're searching for a record based on a non-numeric key (i.e., a string).  You feed that key into a hashing function that spits out an integer value, and you use that value to index into the table.  So if `f("foo")` spits out `3`, that's the table index you use to store your data with the key `"foo"`.

No practical hashing function is perfect and different strings can result in the same hash value, known as a *collision*.  Using a linked list is one way to resolve collisions, other ways are to compute a secondary index into the table or just add 1 to the returned index.

Computing a hash from the key is *fast* relative to a linear or binary search, giving a time complexity of O(1) compared to a linear search time of O(n) and a binary search time of O(log<sub>2</sub> n).  The tradeoff is that your table isn't *ordered* in any way - a linear traverse will appear randomly ordered.

**Edit**

From the comment:

> i need to save a text as a bunch of lines, so i know where each line is (line 1 will be the first, duh) and it did seem unnecessary to me to use hash table but the problem is I don't know how many lines it will have so if i make an array of 50 maybe it's not enough, I am wondering if it is better to use a list/hash table/ some other structure or just an array of char arrays (added in post too)

If you just need to store a sequence of strings, you can dynamically allocate an array and then extend that array as necessary.  Assuming all the lines are of a known fixed length, you can do something like this (reads the file into memory, dumps the contents to standard output):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 80

size_t read_arr( FILE *in, char (**arr)[MAX_LENGTH+1] ) 
{
  size_t size = 1;
  size_t read = 0;

  *arr = malloc( sizeof **arr * size );
  if ( !*arr )
  {
    return 0;
  }

  char buf[MAX_LENGTH+1];
  while( fgets( buf, sizeof buf, in ) )
  {
    if ( read == size )
    {
      char (*tmp)[MAX_LENGTH+1] = realloc( *arr, sizeof **arr * (size * 2) );
      if ( tmp )
      {
        *arr = tmp;
        size *= 2;
      }
      else
      {
        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to extend array past %zu entries, returning what we have so far.\n", read );
        return read;
      }
    }
    strcpy( (*arr)[read++], buf );
  }
  return read;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  if ( argc < 2 )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <file name>\n", argv[0] );
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  FILE *in = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
  if ( !in )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "File %s not found\n", argv[0] );
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  char (*arr)[MAX_LENGTH+1];
  size_t n = read_arr( in, &arr );

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    printf( "%s", arr[i] );

  free( arr );
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`realloc` is a relatively expensive operation, so you don't want to do it for every line in the file.  Doubling the array each time minimizes the number of calls, although the tradeoff is the possibility of internal fragmentation (needing 256 rows to store 129 lines, for example).  But on average that shouldn't be a problem.

> could you tell me what is `char (**arr)[MAX_LENGTH+1]`, I've never seen this structure; is it a 2d array?

Yeah, I guess I should explain that.

```
T (*a)[N];
```

declares `a` as a *pointer* to an N-element array of `T`.  An expression of type `T [M][N]` will "decay" to type `T (*)[N]` (**not** `T **`).

I want to dynamically allocate enough space to store M objects of type `T [N]`.  So we start with the common idiom

```
P *p = malloc( sizeof *p * M );
```

`sizeof *p` is equivalent to `sizeof (P)`, so we're allocating enough space to store M objects of type `P`.  Now we replace the type `P` with the *array* type `T [N]`, which gives us

```
T (*p)[N] = malloc( sizeof *p * M );
```

In this case, `sizeof *p` is equivalent to `sizeof (T [N])`, so we're allocating enough space to store M N-element arrays of `T`.

Since `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)`, the following is true:

```
(*p)[i] == (*(p + 0))[i] == (p[0])[i] == p[0][i]
```

So we can index into `p` like any other 2D array.

So in the `main` function above, I declare `arr` as a pointer to a `MAX_LENGTH+1` array of `char`.  Since I want `read_arr` to update the value stored in `arr` itself (the address to the allocated memory), I need to pass a *pointer* to `arr`.  Remember, if you want a function to update one of its parameters, you must pass a *pointer* to that parameter<sup>1</sup>, even if that parameter is already a pointer type.  If the type of `arr` is `char (*)[MAX_LENGTH+1]`, then the type of `&arr` is `char (**)[MAX_LENGTH+1]`, or "pointer to pointer to `MAX_LENGTH+1`-element array of `char`".

And again, this assumes that all the lines in the file are close to the same length, and that they're all less than some known maximum length.  If you have a file where the lines have wildly different lengths, or 99% have length 20 and one or two have length 200, then you'll want to do something else.

---

1. Arrays are weird, but we're not dealing with an array type in this case, we're dealing with a pointer type.

Comment: i need to save a text as a bunch of lines, so i know where each line is (line 1 will be the first, duh) and it did seem unnecessary to me to use hash table but the problem is I don't know how many lines it will have so if i make an array of 50 maybe it's not enough, I am wondering if it is better to use a list/hash table/ some other structure or just an array of char arrays (added in post too)

Comment: could you tell me what is `char (**arr)[MAX_LENGTH+1]`, I've never seen this structure; is it a 2d array?

Answer (score 1):

A hash table is a data structure that allows for fast retrieval of a data item given a key.

A hash table is indexed using a *hash* of the key. It maps the key onto an integer that is used to index the table. The hash function is generally very fast.

The hash table is generally much smaller than the number of possible keys. Because of this, the hash function can generate the same index for more than one distinct key. This is called a *collision*. To handle collisions, a hash table entry generally has a linked list (but a balanced binary tree could also be possible). The list stores all the collisions of the hash table entry.

So given a key, the hash function determines the index into the table and then the list of that entry is searched for the actual key and then the data associated with that key is retrieved. As you see, this is much faster than searching a linked list, and uses a lot less memory than an array that has an entry for every possible key.

There is some overhead in maintaining the table and list, but the main gain is the fast data retrieval.

Designing hash functions is a science in itself.

Note: so a hash table consists of two data structures: the hash table itself with its size and hash function, and the hash table entry which could be a list, a sorted list, a tree or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can. If you have that much memory. But from a statistical point of view a hashtable will be just as good. They have O(1) lookup on *average*. This may be hard to realize how and why, so my tip would be to try implementing your own just to learn. Also, malloc calls shouldn't be slow on a good OS.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually very simple.

The reason you can't use a 20 billion long array is because it will take 80 gigabytes of RAM. 160 gigabytes if it's 64-bit.

Also you can't index them with strings. `myArray["hello"] = "world";` is never ever ever ever going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array is useful if you already know the index of every element to search for, to reduce time for all operations.

On the memory part, because arrays have fixed dimension it all comes down if you know the total data you have to save or not; because if "just to be sure" you make an array with 20 billion indexes and then end up using only the first 100 it is quite a poor choice compared to using dynamic memory, which can extend itself only in case more space is needed.